# Отключения JS-скрипта

Tags: javascript

Некая CMS отрисовует теги  со старыми неактуальными src. В самой CMS найти тот самый участок кода, который "пакостит" не удается. Мой хитрый план состоит в том, чтобы отменить подключение этих "старых" скриптов и на их место вставить  со "свежими" src.

Вопрос заключается в том, как отменить подключение CMS-ных скриптов при помощи js, а не просто удалить их из DOM.

Edit: правка самого src при помощи js так же не решает проблему

Comment: При всём трагизме положения, симпозиум аквазеленения биоквадратных функтуаций, с точки банальной эрудиции, эгоизм каждого индивидума ассоциируется  в моём познании как пароксодальность илюзий....  Немножко юмора ))

Comment: Andrew вы поняли мой коммент ? правильно - нет, то же самое с вашим вопросом, ничего не понятно. Какой CMS , какие файлы подгружает, что за старые , что за новые файлы вы хотите подключить ? и т.д  ` отпечатка *параксадальность`
Почитайте тут  https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2487/%D0%A5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0

Comment: Arsen, предположим есть участок html <script src="old_src"></script>. Этот src (!) неактуален. Нужно каким-то неведомым мне и вобще хз реальным ли образом заменить <script src="old_src"></script> на <script src="new_src"></script> так, чтобы <script src="old_src"></script> не подключался вообще. Зачем вот этой инфы: "Какой CMS , какие файлы подгружает, что за старые , что за новые файлы вы хотите подключить ?"?

Comment: при указании конкретной CMS можно дать конкретный (более оптимальный) ответ, вы же сами указали что используете CMS...

Comment: В зависимости от CMS меняется js-код?.. Немножко юмора ))

Comment: > В самой CMS найти тот самый участок кода, в зависимости от CMS меняется место для подключения файлов....  Диагноз понятен... удачи )

Comment: Arsen,  перечитайте текст после "Вопрос заключается в том" пожалуйста) А за удачу большое спасибо)

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy  воочию. Вы не хотите забивать гвозди молотком, вы спрашиваете как починить микроскоп.

Comment: Klimenkomud, перефразирую: "можно ли при помощи js отменить подключение какого-либо (ни в коем случае не CMS-ного) скрипта? предположим скрипта <script id='not-from-CMS' scr='some_src.js'></script>"

Answer (score -1):

```js
  var elem = document.getElementById('myScript');
  elem.remove();
```

```html
<script id='myScript' scr='some_src.js'></script>
```

Comment: к сожалению, этот код удаляет из DOM <script id='myScript' scr='some_src.js'></script> уже после того как сам файл some_src.js сработал